# Javascript substring with html tags

Tags: javascript, substring

I have searched too much on same topic but not is perfect for what I am looking for.

I have a string like :

```
var string ='<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <span>string<span></p></strong>'
```

Now what I want is to substring it with limit with javascript substring function but don't want tags to be cut in middle like for example

```
<strong><span>Hii </span> <p
```

It should be like

```
<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>
```

I am using

```
string.substr(0,200)
```

string is dynamic variable with html tags

Comment: i don't know exactly about your meaning...you did't want to break the couple symbol,right?

Comment: Either look into regex matching, or (hax) make a new element with the HTML code you've got and get its contents.

Comment: no I don't want to break html tags lets say I have limit my text to 28 characters so it will cut <p> tag but it should check that if tag is not finished then increase limit accordingly or reduce limit accordingly

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly do you want to cut out? Only the given example? Please post your code with the substring.

Comment: Is it the text inside the tags you want limited, or the html in whole?

Comment: whole html I want to limit but just need to make sure that html tag can not be cut in between like <spa <stro it should be like <span> <strong> even if limit is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not elegant but it works, will increase the characters to include the next closing tag
https://jsfiddle.net/q680vors/

Just change length to the required number of characters.

```
var string ='<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <span>string<span></p></strong>';

var length = 2;
var openTag = 0, closeTag = 0,i=0;
for(i; i<length; i++)
{
    if(string[i] == "<")
        openTag++;
    if(string[i] == ">")
        closeTag++;
}
if(openTag > closeTag)
{
    while(string[i] != ">")
        i++;
}

var newString = string.substring(0,(i+1));

alert(newString);
```

Comment: Just seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29699608/1286358, its far more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

```
function smart_substr(str, len) {
    var temp = str.substr(0, len);
    if(temp.lastIndexOf('<') > temp.lastIndexOf('>')) {
        temp = str.substr(0, 1 + str.indexOf('>', temp.lastIndexOf('<')));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8t6fs67n/

Comment: Nice and smart one!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see reason to do so, but theoretically something like this:

```
function substrWithTags(str, len) {
    var result = str.substr(0, len),
        lastOpening = result.lastIndexOf('<'),
        lastClosing = result.lastIndexOf('>');

    if (lastOpening !== -1 && (lastClosing === -1 || lastClosing < lastOpening)) {
        result += str.substring(len, str.indexOf('>', len) + 1);
    }

    return result;
}

var s = '<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <span>string<span></p></strong>'

// <strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <spa
s.substr(0, 53);

// <strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <span>
substrWithTags(s, 53);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think my function is more accurate when it comes to being more sensitive on the content syntax. If your substring length cuts a word in half for example, the word will be included fully.

```
function HTML_substring(string, length) {

    var noHTML = string.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    var subStringNoHTML = noHTML.substr(0, noHTML.indexOf(" ", length));
    var words = subStringNoHTML.split(" ");

    var outPutString = "";
    var wordIndexes = [];

    words.forEach((word, key) => {

        if (key == 0) {

            outPutString += string.substr(0, string.indexOf(word) + word.length);
            wordIndexes[key] = string.indexOf(word) + word.length;

        } else {

            let i = wordIndexes[key - 1];

            outPutString += string.substring(i, string.indexOf(word, i) + word.length);
            wordIndexes[key] = string.indexOf(word, i) + word.length;

        }
    });

    return outPutString;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to to do something like this?

```
var limit = 28;
var test = '';
var string = '<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <span>string<span></p></strong>';

    do {
          test = string.substring(0,limit); 
          limit++;
    } while(test.charAt(test.length-1) !== '>');


test will be equal to '<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>'
```

or will ends with any another closing tag which is above your limit

Comment: my solution is not the best one, look at responce of @SimonPlus

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did [a function](http://jsfiddle.net/gLtqu3fk/):

```
function my_substring (str) {
    var answer = [], x;
    for (var i=0, l=str.length; i<l; i++) {
        x = i;
        if (str[i] == '<') {
            while (str[++i] != '>');
            answer.push( str.substring(x, i+1) );
        }
        else {
            while (++i < l && str[i] != '<');
            answer.push( str.substring(x, i) );
            i--;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

var string = 
"<strong><span>Hii </span> <p>this is just a demo <span>string<span></p></strong>"

console.log ( my_substring(string) );
```

---

This code will output:

```
["<strong>", 
 "<span>", 
 "Hii ", 
 "</span>", 
 " ", 
 "<p>", 
 "this is just a demo ", 
 "<span>", 
 "string", 
 "<span>", 
 "</p>", 
 "</strong>"
]
```

Then you can select what you want in the array. Hope it helps.